# Pass Integer to BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-intent, baseadapter

I am trying to pass an integer array to a baseadapter, such that A.class will pass an array of integers to the BaseAdapter in B.class. Here is how I am passing the integer array in A.Class (sender):

```
int [] mThumb = {
                     R.drawable.image1_thumb, R.drawable.image2_thumb, R.drawable.image3_thumb,
                     R.drawable.image4_thumb, R.drawable.image5_thumb, R.drawable.image6_thumb,
                     R.drawable.image7_thumb, R.drawable.image8_thumb, R.drawable.image9_thumb,
                     R.drawable.image10_thumb};


        Bundle b=new Bundle();
        b.putIntArray("mThumbSent", mThumb);
        Intent startSwitcher = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
        startSwitcher.putExtras(b);
```

And in my BaseAdapter in activity B:

```
public class ImageSwitch1 extends Activity Extends ...{
onCreate....
[redacted]
}

private ImageSwitcher mSwitcher;


public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
    int[] mThumb = b.getIntArray("mThumbSent");

     public ImageAdapter(Context c) {

        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {

    return mThumb.length; //this used to say return mThumbIds

    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView im = new ImageView(mContext);
        im.setImageResource(mThumb[position]);
        im.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        im.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        im.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture_frame);


        return im;
    }

    private Context mContext;

}
}
```

now obviously the code above is incorrect, I cannot use getintent in the imageadapter. But this is an illustrative example of what I am trying to accomplish, and would like to know how to pass a variable or array via intent to a BaseAdapter, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the constructor of your ImageAdapter to accept an integer array like so:

```
int[] mResources;

public ImageAdapter(Context c, int[] resources) {
    mResources = resources;
    mContext = c;
}
```

Then when initializing your Adapter in your Activity, just pass it the extra int array:

```
ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(context, intArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

getIntent() will be available in your class B.

You could put the Bundle or the integer array into the constructor of your ImageAdapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, Bundle b) {
        int[] mThumb = b.getIntArray("mThumbSent");
        mContext = c;
    }

    .....
}
```

In your Activity B construct your Adapter this way:

```
ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(yourcontext,getIntent().getExtras());
```

Where do you want to use your adapter? In a ListView? Then it would be enough to subclass ListAdapter instead of BaseAdapter.